# It is ok to put conditions on function names?

Tags: coding-style

I would like to create a function named `highlightHeaderIfFormIsValid(form: Form)`, but I'm not sure if it's ok to put `IfFormIsValid` in its name. What would be a good alternative?

Comment: This might work better on our sister site [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).  Also, you should include more code sot that the function is in context.

Comment: I would ask this question there, but they don't have a tag for coding style, that's why I asked it at Stack Overflow. Thank you!

Comment: For answering your question, I believe it would be helpful if you could provide some background information: Are you adhering/attempting to adhere to a specific style guide? How are such things handled in the code base so far (consistency)?

Answer (score 0):

I like to apply the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) all the way down to function level. It feels like your method is performing two tasks: assessing if the form is valid & highlighting the header. If it were me, I would go for something like:

```
if (FormIsValid())
{
   HighlightHeader();
}
```

This way you create two reusable functions that can be called independently while still retaining good readability.